# How to start coding Cardano Smart Contracts?

Tags: smart-contract

I have some ideas which including the use of smart contracts. The thing is that i don't know anything coding them. So my question is, where should i start to learn doing it. I mean every programmer had to start somewhere... It would be a blessing if someone could help me out!

Thanks and regards,

Lukas

Answer (score 2):

Here are the [Plutus Pioneer Program lectures](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLK8ah7DzglhgV7W6BHcoIzRArjzs_UuSY). This is how most of us learned how to write Plutus Smart Contracts.

They will require you to have a basic understanding of Haskell and the ecosystem. If you need a crash course for Haskell, I would recommend [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) as the canonical tutorial. IOHK also provides a comprehensive video course [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLJ3w5xyG4JWmBVIigNBytJhvSSfZZzfTm).

People on this site are also generally willing to answer questions you have along the way.